# How do I access form data submitted by a user in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, form-submit

I'm relatively new to programming, but understand the basics of HTML, CSS, and Javascript (including jQuery).  Due to my greenness, I'd appreciate it if answers contained both a simple solution and a reason as to *why* the solution works.  Thanks!

So I've got a form, with a text input and a submit button:

```
<form>
<input type="text">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When the user types data into the text field and clicks submit, how do I gain access to this data?  If a user inputs their name, how do I grab that information?  I don't intend to store it or write it anywhere, just to hold onto it as a variable in javascript, which I'll assign to a jQuery cookie.

So how do I access the data that the user has submitted, preferably using only Javascript (with jQuery)?  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

say you had an html input tag such as:

```
<input id="textfield" type="text">
```

using javascript, you can store the value of that field in a variable like this:

```
var inputvalue = $('#textfield').val();
```

of course, you'll need something to run the script.

the reason this works is that the the textfield is an object. you might think of it as a tree trunk with different branches coming out.  one of these "branches" is the value contained inside of it.  since you know jquery, you know that `$('#textfield')` gets the element by a selector.  the period says we're getting one of the branches, and "value" says we want the branch that tells what's in the textfield.

hope this helps.

Comment: I replaced the button within the form with a div, as it being a button sort of messes things up.  The div has an onclick of `upl();`.  In my Javascript, the function `upl()` looks like this:

`function upl(){
var inputvalue=$("#textfield").value;
console.log(inputvalue);`

I forgot to mention, in my HTML, I added the ID of "textfield" to the text input.  When I click the button now, all it logs is "undefined."  What have I done wrong?

Comment: oops. should be var inputvalue = $('#textfield').val() in jquery.  edited.

Answer (score 3):

You access the data on the server side (in PHP via `$_POST['username']` for example).  The form sends data to your sever for any named input, so you would probably have to change the input to:

```
<input type=text name=username>
```

If you want to access it on the client side (with JavaScript), you can do that too, but you have to prevent the form from submitting:

```
$("form").on('submit', function (e) {
    $.cookie('username', $(this).find('[name=username]').val());
    //stop form from submitting
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I'm definitely accessing client side, as I don't know anything about PHP.  I understand that this means I can't store the data for use in any other way than a cookie, and that's no worries.

To get the username value into a variable instead of a cookie, would it just be 
`var un = $('username').find('[name=username]').val();` to store the username in variable `un`?

Comment: @IanZane close.  `'username'` tries to select an actual element like `<username>`.  I used `this` (and you should too) which is the form element that was submitted.